# What's the difference between these three ways to create DIY stucts?

Tags: go

There is a struct `User`, and what's the differences between `user := User{}`, `var user User` and `user := new(User)` in GoLang?

Comment: The first 2 is basically identical, the third will be a pointer to `User`, thus `*User`, same as `user := &User{}`.

Answer (score 3):

`user := User{}` creates a new user struct with default values and is the same as `var user User`. `var user User` would be more common to use if no values are set.

`user := new(User)` creates a variable with a pointer to `User` (type `*User`). Identical to `user := &User{}`. You see the `user := &User{}` notation more often. The `new` keyword comes in handy for initializing types like `*int` or `*string` to be non-nil.